# Relative URLs in HTML when routing some subset of requests through nodejs middleware

Tags: html, node.js, express

Ok, so the title tells very little of my issue.

Basically, I have a project written in node that does something. It's a website that uses express, jade and stylus. I have set up the routing for static content like this:
`app.use(express.static('public'));`

The website works fine and all the CSS loads properly if, in the HTML, I reference it like this (for example):
`link(rel="stylesheet", href="global.css")`

As expected, when I hover over the link in Chrome's element viewer, the URL is `localhost/global.css`

So now I've got a couple of these little project and I want to put them all together. They aren't related but I'd like to put them all on my website. For this I have made a new project that server like a hub for the other ones.

In it, I've setup routing like this:

```
var proj = require("../proj/server.js");
app.use("/proj ", proj);
```

and in each of the projects I have set the modules exports like this `module.exports = app` where app is their respective express app object.

This also worked like a charm. I didn't have to run a separate server instance on a separate port for each project. Instead, you can access them like `localhost/proj/`

Now here's where the issue starts. The CSS that is referenced in the generated HTML of each project doesn't point to `localhost/proj/global.css`. Instead it still points to `localhost/global.css`. And since there's no `global.css` in the public folder of my hub application, it doesn't find it.

I could, of course, just change the relative URLs to `proj/global.css` instead of just `global.css` and this does work, but it means that I need to modify all of my projects. It also means that I have one more string to change should I decide to change their names.

Besides, the URL already shows `localhost/proj`, so why can't it just be automatically implied that when I reference `global.css` it should be looked for in `localhost/proj/global.css`?

I'm sure there's some easy trick I'm missing. Maybe my relative URLs should have some extra stuff that says it refers to the current URL?

Edit:
It actually seems that the relative URLs work, but only if the address in the address bar is `localhost/proj/`. If it's `localhost/proj` it doesn't. What can I do to force that last slash?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help you, but in express, you can define several "public" directories

```
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')));
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'foo')));
```